# "replace" vs. "substitute"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences

When you *replace somebody with somebody else*, does it refer to a permanent change usually for a better one?

In "The company replaced Alice with a new secretary", does it refer to a permanent change?

What about *substitute*? When you *substitute somebody for somebody else*, is this change permanent or temporary? Like in a game when the coach substitutes a player for another?

I know you can say "The teacher was sick, so Jane substituted for her", and it means Jane is supposed to do the teacher's job until she's able to do it herself again.

Can you also use the structure with two objects to say that we put someone in the place of someone else temporarily until they can do it themselves again, in a sentence like "The teacher was sick so the school substituted Jane for her"?

Comment: you've already got it. replaced does give a more permanent feeling, while substitute not so much.

Comment: @user3306356 I agreee substitute *seems* more temporary (as I think of football substitutes or substitute teachers). [This site](http://www.queens-english-society.com/guide_10.html) reckons they just mean the same thing from different POV though `If you substitute B for A, then you replace A by B` i.e. "The school substituted Jane for Jill" = "The school replaced Jill by Jane"

Comment: @MartinSmith -Can we also use 'with' instead of 'by' in your sentence? And also does this sentence make sense to you? "It was the few last minutes of the game that James substituted for Smith"?

Comment: @MartinSmith - The use of 'substitute' as a verb in sports (and perhaps for teachers) has a different derivation; basically a back construction of using a substitute player. It is my hypothesis that this is what has led to the sloppy nondirectional usage of 'substitute' prevalent today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These verbs both mean to put someone or something in the place of another. To replace is to be or to furnish an equivalent or substitute, especially for one that has been lost, depleted, worn out, or discharged:

To [*replace*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/replace):

> to provide a substitute for (something broken or unsatisfactory, for example) - AHDEL

To [*substitute*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substitute):

> To put or use (a person or thing) in place of another - AHDEL

While the two are synonyms, replace does carry a stronger connotation of being long-term.

The etymology of [substitute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/substitute), particularly the prefix "[sub](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sub-)" may suggest why it has a weaker connotation of being permanent:

> Origin
>
> late Middle English (denoting a deputy or delegate):
>
> from Latin substitutus 'put in place of',
>
> past participle of substituere,
>
> sub 'under + statuere 'set up'.

*Substitute* is rendered from it's Latin origin: "set up under"

> PREFIX
>
> 1 At, to, or from a lower level or position:
>
> *sub*alpine
>
> 1.1 Lower in rank:
>
> *sub*altern
>
> *sub*deacon

Although permanent replacement is CURRENTLY an acceptable use of *substitute*, it's original use was closer to "deputy". A *substitute* would stand in for the principle as a duputy:

- a deputy "replaces" the sheriff who ordered him to execute the warrant
- the corporate vice-president "replaces" the president who is out of town
- margarine "replaces" butter when it is not available
- a temp "replaces" the secretary while she is on vacation

Each of those "replacements" is temporary because the principal remains available "above" her *substitute*.

Edited to add: As @John Lawler points out, they are the same but serve opposite rhetorical functions: he *replaced* 'old' with 'new'; he *substituted* 'new' for 'old'.

Comment: @ScotM - Wow! Thank you for that edit! (Now if we could split the rep...) :D

Comment: I'm already a legend in my own mind, @Medica. What others think of me is a trifle ;) Besides, you upgraded one of my earlier successful answers. Turnabout's fair play!

Comment: _Replace_ and _substitute_ do mean the same thing, but in opposite directions. In each case, there is a `New` and an `Old`, but the patterns go like this: _He replaced `Old` with `New`_ = _He substituted `New` for `Old`_. Having two verbs lets you use either order, to suit your rhetorical purposes.

Comment: @JohnLawler - hmm, that's very interesting. I couldn't have put it like that, but recognize its validity immediately. Thank you!

Comment: That's the way things usually go -- variation in the word pool produces adaptation to specific niches.